# Struct initialization and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization

Is the initialization of the members of a structure is uncertain in the derived structures when the inheritance is used?

In this example:

```
struct A {
  double x0[2], x1[2];
};
struct B : A {
  double x2[2], x3[2];
};
struct C {
  A a;
  B b;
  C(): a(), b() {
    printf("a.x0[0]=%f, a.x1[0]=%f\n", a.x0[0], a.x1[0]);
    printf("b.x2[0]=%f, b.x3[0]=%f\n", b.x2[0], b.x3[0]);
  }
};
int main() {
  C c;
}
```

`b.x2[0]`, `b.x3[0]` are not always null, my question is why this happen this?

Nr two question: `a.x0[0]`, `a.x1[0]` are always null ?

Comment: "_b.x2[0], b.x3[0] are not always null,_": With the code you are showing the output must always be zero (for rather subtle reasons). What compiler are you using that gives you a different output?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in `std::printf`, to be pedantic. The OP code is ill-formed due to no declaration of `printf`

Comment: I think `b()` has implied zero-initialization since C++03  . OP could be using a very old compiler (e.g. the Borland 32-bit compiler used C++98 initialization even into the 2010s)

Comment: @M.M: you think incorrectly.  Using aggregate initialization (`b{}`) would zero-initialize the array elements.

Comment: @user17732522 Why must the output always be zero? I was looking into the rules of initialization and couldn't find the information which states that.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan Since C++03 `a()` and `b()` in `C`'s constructor are _value-initialization_ of `a` and `b`. Because both `A` and `B` have non-user-declared non-deleted default constructors, this means that `a` and `b` are zero-initialized before their constructors are called. And I think this was supposed to be a defect report against C++98 as well, so except for ancient compilers none _should_ behave differently.

Comment: Caty please edit the question to be a Minimal Reproducible Example (i.e. it should compile and run with no further modifications to demonstrate your point)

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; The array data members are *zero initialized*.

---

Let's see what is happening here in steps:

**Step 1:** `C c` is default initialization. This means that the default ctor `C::C()` will be used.

---

**Step 2:** Next, the default ctor has *member initializer list* for the data members `a` and `b` which **value initializes** those two data members. That is, *value initialization* takes place for data members `a` and `b` since `a()` and `b()` is the syntax(in this case of member initializer list) for value initialization.

This can be seen from [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

> Value initialization is performed in these situations:
>
> - **when a non-static data member or a base class is initialized using a member initializer with an empty pair of parentheses** or braces (since C++11);

---

**Step 3:** As a result both `a` and `b` are **zero initialized** as quoted below:

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> - **if `T` is a class type with a default constructor that is not user-declared (until C++11)neither user-provided nor deleted (since C++11) (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized** and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

---

**Step 4:** Finally as a result of [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), the array data members themselves are zero initialized.

> The effects of zero-initialization are:
>
> - **If `T` is a non-union class type:**
>
>   - - **each non-static data member is zero-initialized**

Comment: Correct so far, although also not answering the question  of why OP sees non-zero output

Answer (score -1):

The compiler-generated *default-constructor* of a class type will *default-initialize* all the members of the class.  Here, since your `C()` constructor calls those default constructors for `A` and `B`, that is what happens.

When you explicitly initialize a member with `()` in a member initializer list, that causes *value-initialization*, the effect of which depends on what that member is.  When the member is a non-class type, it will cause it to be *zero-initialized`, but in this example it is a class type, so is *default-initialized*

When an object of array type is *default-initialized*, each element of the array is *default-initialized*.  When an object of non-class type (such as `double`) and non-static storage duration is *default-initialized*, **no initializarion occurs**

So in this case, the elements of the arrays (in both `c.a` and `c.b`) are uninitialized and have undefined values.

If you want to explicitly zero those arrays (in `A` and `B`) you'll need to initialize them in the constructors of `A` and `B`.

Comment: `a()` and `b()` are value-initialization, so they cause zero-initialization of `a` and `b`. That's been different only before C++03.

Comment: Is newer then C++03

Comment: Chris Dodd you miss a(), b() on the C() constructor

Comment: since C++03, syntax `a()` in member initializer list means *value-initialization*, whose definition includes zero-initialization of any class without a user-provided constructor . See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization point 3

Comment: @M.M: zero-initialization only applies to non-class types.  As the link you provide shows, class types with no constructor will be default-initialized, not zero-initialized.  (point 1 in the effects of value initialization listed there)

Comment: @Caty: no, I did not miss it -- you're misunderstanding how value initialization works when applied to class types.

Comment: @ChrisDodd That's not correct since resolution of [CWG 178](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/178.html) for C++03 (further corrected by [CWG 543](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/543.html)). In the link to cppreference item 2) applies, not 1), and therefore zero-initialization is performed fot the whole `a` and `b` objects, even if they are of class type.

Comment: @ChrisDodd your assertion "zero-initialization only applies to non-class types" is contradicted by the link I posted (which itself is supported by the language standard) . "if T is a class type with a default constructor that is {not user-declared (until C++11) / neither user-provided nor deleted (since C++11)} (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized."

Comment: `A` and `B` have a default constructor that is implicitly defined, so point 1 does not apply and point 2 does